# Static Dictionary needs to be threadsafe - Suggestions?

Tags: c#

I currently have a static dictionary in my class. Although I have implemented locks on this dictionary yet I get the following error.

```
An InvalidOperationException has occurred. It reports a "collection was modified" error
```

The reason for this is that at times one method is reading the dictionary using foreach while another thread is removing or adding items to it. I read that adding

```
lock ( (  (IDictionary<string,string>)dict_object).SyncRoot )
```

on all the operations where reading/writing/removing is taking place will resolve the issue however I keep on getting the message

```
does not contain a definition of SyncRoot are you missing a using directive
```

any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue ? Any other way on how I could make my static dictionary threadsafe ? I am using .Net 4.0

Comment: I extended my answer by.. well, an actual answer to your question.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple: Use the `ConcurrentDictionary` class instead of a `Dictionary`. It is a thread-safe dictionary implementation available in .NET 4.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.100).aspx

The reason for your error is that `SyncRoot` is defined in the `ICollection` interface and is implemented `explicitly` in the `Dictionary` class. So in order to access it you need to cast your instance to `ICollection`.

```
((ICollection)dict_object).SyncRoot
```